# How to make google graph the min and max value?

Tags: graphing-functions, math-software

I can put e.g. `sin(x),cos(x)` in google's search box and it will plot the 2 functions. But if I only want to plot the maximum value, how do I plot something like `max(sin(x),cos(x))` or the minimum ? I'm not sure but if the max and min are not implemented maybe trigonometric functions can implement the max / min functions?

### Update

I was not clear enough. I want something like `max(sin(x), 0.5x)` and only plot the maximum value at each x.

Comment: You mean like [*this*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5BMax%5B%7BSin%5Bx%5D%2CCos%5Bx%5D%7D%5D%5D) and [*this*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5BMin%5B%7BSin%5Bx%5D%2CCos%5Bx%5D%7D%5D%5D)? Maybe get MMA or some other [*CAS*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems).

Comment: Find your answer below!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use $\frac{sin(x)+cos(x)+|sin(x)-cos(x)|}{2}$ or `(sin(x)+cos(x)+abs(sin(x)-cos(x)))/2` for max(sin(x),cos(x)) and $\frac{sin(x)+cos(x)-|sin(x)-cos(x)|}{2}$ for min(sin(x),cos(x)).

like [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=%28sin%28x%29%2bcos%28x%29%2babs%28sin%28x%29-cos%28x%29%29%29/2).

EDIT: Seems like I wasn't clear enough, for any arbitrary f(x) and g(x) you can use `1/2*(f(x)+g(x)+abs(f(x)-g(x)))` to plot `max(f(x),g(x))`.

EDIT 2: Note that
$$
\forall x, f(x) < g(x): |f(x) - g(x)| = g(x) - f(x) \implies f(x) + g(x) + |f(x) - g(x)| = 2g(x). 
$$

$$
\forall x, f(x) > g(x): |f(x) - g(x)| = f(x) - g(x) \implies f(x) + g(x) + |f(x) - g(x)| = 2f(x).
$$

$$
\implies \forall x: f(x) + g(x) + |f(x) - g(x)| = 2* max(f(x),g(x)).
$$

$$
\square
$$

Comment: You beat me to it by a second :) +1

Comment: Thank you but I think I want it more general i.e. `max(f(x),g(x))` and I was not clear enough in the post.

Comment: Just replace the sin and cos with f and g. Edited.

Comment: Great, I do believe it's working when I input `1/2*(sin(x)+0.5*(x)+abs(sin(x)+0.5*(x)))` to google's search and it graphs just the maximum value of sin(x) och 0.5*x

Comment: Proved it will work in any case :). Edited, second.

Comment: This is extremely useful. For example, I can plot the max of x² and 5x by entering `1/2*((x^2)+(5x)+abs((x^2)-(5x)))`

Comment: Or `1/2*(exp(sin(x))+cos(exp(x^4))+abs(exp(sin(x))-cos(exp(x^4))))`!

Comment: Can it be generalized to an arbitrary number of functions?

Comment: Well, it will be ugly. Use the fact that `max(f,g,h) = max(f,max(g,h))`. example: `max(sin(x),cos(x),tan(x))` will be `1/2*(sin(x)+(1/2*(cos(x)+tan(x)+abs(cos(x)-tan(x)))+abs(sin(x)-(1/2*(cos(x)+tan(x)+abs(cos(x)-tan(x)))))`. I don't know if google's engine will parse such a big string as a formula or not.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20%28max%28sin%28x%29,cos%28x%29%29) to get [image: this]

Comment: Why can't google do simple math? Thanks for the answer. Google could let us make a macro or so for the max and min.